# FreeBSD 9 - default file system?

Tags: filesystems, freebsd

What will the default file system be in FreeBSD 9?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's still UFS. The installer (`bsdinstall` as of 9.0) cannot install to a ZFS filesystem.

If you want ZFS for your root filesystem you need to do a fully manual install.

Comment: That's frustrating that ZFS doesn't work by using the installer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Do you know if there is plan (when) to have ZFS work using the bsdinstaller?

Comment: I don't believe there is a firm plan yet. You're better off asking on the current@ or stable@ mailing list. For now if you want ZFS the wiki has [several good guides](http://wiki.freebsd.org/RootOnZFS). I've used this successfully on several servers.

Comment: http://mfsbsd.vx.sk also has a script that automates installation of FreeBSD 9 with ZFS as the root filesystem.

Comment: Not to be offensive, but if you don't know how to install on ZFS manually it's probably a good idea not to be using it as the root FS. ZFS is quite different from UFS in many important administrative ways and the switch should not be taken lightly.

Answer (score 2):

PC-BSD installer can install FreeBSD on ZFS. As soon as the installation start, you may choose you want to install FreeBSD (instead of PC-BSD) and then the installer lets you partition your disk using ZFS.